# Почему объект "студент" не переводится на следующий курс, если добавить условие проверки?

Tags: php, if

Уже мозг сломал, пытаясь найти ошибку, начал изучать классы и методы, задание вроде как элементарное, написать метод, переводящий объект "студент" на следующий курс.

Пока надо было просто перевести его, всё работало, но когда я добавил проверку на то, что курс на который я его перевожу не больше 5, всё сломалось и я не могу понять в чём проблема, уже раз 100 перечитал код.

```
<?php
class Student
{
    private $name;
    private $course;
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->course = 1;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this->course;
    }
    // public function transferToNextCourse()
    // {
    //     $this->course++;
    // }
    public function checkCourse($course)
    {
        if ($course <= 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function transferToNextCourse()
    {
        $newCourse = $this->course++;
        if($this->checkCourse($newCourse)) {
            $this->course = $newCourse;
        } 
    }
}
```

При проверке работы кода, курс студента до и после перевода остаётся равен 1

```
<?php
require_once 'Student.php';

$student16 = new Student('Andrew');
echo $student16->getCourse();
$student16->transferToNextCourse();

echo '<br>';
echo $student16->getCourse();
```

**Дополнение**: Написал `+ 1` вместо `++` и всё магическим образом заработало, только не понятно почему так.

Comment: Написал + 1 вместо ++ и всё магическим образом заработало, только не понятно почему так.

Comment: *"только не понятно почему так"* --- Потому что надо знать разницу между преинкрементом и постинкрементом  (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: В итоге можно было написать `$newCourse = ++$this->course`

Comment: А вообще надо было в методе `checkCourse` написать код вот такой: `function checkCourse() { return $this->course + 1 <= 5; }` и всё... а в методе `transferToNextCourse` оставить как было раньше `$this->course++;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский точно, я вообще про это забыл,спасибо! Только вот теперь не работает проверка, то есть я могу увеличивать курс студента после 5. Вероятно это происходит потому что $this->course увеличивается на 1 и без проверки, но если добавить else в условие, всё работает как надо!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что-то на гениальном, очень красиво, но я бы не додумался, по крайней мере не сейчас) Но спасибо, я запомню, выглядит красиво!

Comment: *"Только вот теперь не работает проверка, то есть я могу увеличивать курс студента после 5"* ---  Так тебе надо проверять check Где-то..  соответственно эту логику надо прописать либо в общем коде через `if (checkCourse()) { transfer() }`  либо в самом методе `transfer()` в классе.... скорее всего должен быть отдельный метод, который объядиняет check и transfer в один и уже его вызывать. Тут уже зависит от логики и требований

Comment: Почему я бы не стал делать `check` непосредственно в методе `transfer` - потому что бывают ситуации, когда надо человека перевести без проверки (по блату например :D). Но в целом если проверка нужна, то где-то её прописывать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это уже хай лвл, мне бы пока с основами разораться, хотя, если предполагать такие исключения, нужно и правда максимально код дробить, а функции чек и трансфер следовало бы поделить на чек, трансфер и внешнее условие для каждого конкретного случая. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

постинкремент (course++) - берет вашу переменную копирует и потом прибавляет 1.

```
int x = 5;
int buf = x;
x = buf + 1;
```

преинкремент (++course) - напрямую прибавляет 1.

```
int x = 5;
x = 1 + x;
```

из-за этого такой код:

```
x = 10;
buf = x++;
//buf == 10
//x == 11


x = 10;
buf = ++x;

//buf == 11
//x == 11
```

Comment: спасибо большое!